# Can I set max task or max memory limits for gevent pools?

Tags: python, django, celery

We are using celery to run asynchronous tasks for a Django site.

The current worker setup is `-pool=prefetch` with `--max-memory-per-child 5120000`. The max memory threshold is important, because our tasks are leaking memory.

Now, we found in a recent analysis that our tasks are I/O bound and would work much better with a thread based execution pool like `gevent`, e.g. we can get much higher throughput.

However, neither the `max-memory-per-child` parameter nor the `max-tasks-per-child` setting are supported for thread based execution pools. The documentation says ([source](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#max-memory-per-child-setting)):

> pool support: prefork

Is they any other celery configuration that could help me limit the max worker memory and/or force a worker restart after x task executions or is our only option to restart the worker with cron?

Comment: I guess the problem is that gevent coroutines all run inside a *single process* so there is no easy way to track down their individual memory usage like you can do with prefork concurrency... I am fairly certain this can't be done without some heavy hacks.

Comment: Makes sense. Personally I would find it sufficient if the limits would apply to the whole process. e.g. if the process is above a memory limit, restart it gracefully and then continue.

Comment: You should be able to easily code that by using psutil to write a tiny monitoring app that sends SIGINT to the worker, and/or create a new one after that...

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I agree that should not be too hard to code. But as it said in my question I am looking for a way to do this within Celery, not be adding any external tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Celery does not support these settings for gevent, there is an alternative solution that I have been using in my production for some time now and which works well.

### Supervisor with superlance

Assuming you are managing your celery workers through [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/), there is a third party plugin called [superlance](https://github.com/Supervisor/superlance), that adds a memory watchdog to supervisor.

The memory watchdog is called [memmon](https://superlance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/memmon.html). Memmon will watch the memory allocation of a program controlled by supervisor and automatically restart it if it surpassed a defined threshold.

### Example

Here is an example supervisor configuration. `worker` is the celery worker program being monitored. Memmon is configured to check every 60 seconds and restart the worker if is surpasses 512MB. Note that Memmon in this configuration will do a "warm shutdown" of the worker, so no data will be lost.

```
[program:worker]
command=/home/allianceserver/venv/auth/bin/celery -A myauth worker -l info --pool=gevent --concurrency=10
directory=/home/allianceserver/myauth
user=allianceserver
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/allianceserver/myauth/log/worker.log
stderr_logfile=/home/allianceserver/myauth/log/worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs=600
killasgroup=true
priority=997

[eventlistener:memmon]
command=/home/allianceserver/venv/auth/bin/memmon -p worker=512MB
directory=/home/allianceserver/myauth
events=TICK_60
```